# FlashDevelop - Disable autocomplete for javascript?

Tags: flashdevelop

FlashDevelop's javascript autocomplete gets it wrong more often than it gets it right. It's horribly frustrating, but I can't figure out how to turn it off - there's no JScriptContext plugin in the settings.

Does anyone know how to turn off autocomplete just for javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools > Program Settings > Basic Completion > Disable (tickbox)

It requires a program restart to take effect, which is why I couldn't figure it out before.

Also, this will disable autocomplete for all languages except ActionScript, which is exactly what I wanted, although I guess I forgot to mention it in the question. Heh.